# Why does SQL Server require the "ONLY" term in OFFSET/FETCH?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

According to [the `OFFSET/FETCH` documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), the grammar for the `FETCH` part of an `OFFSET/FETCH` clause is

```
FETCH {FIRST | NEXT} {integer_constant | fetch_row_count_expression } {ROW | ROWS} ONLY
```

I was aware of the syntax, but I was surprised to find that `ONLY` is a required constant in the grammar, rather than being optional or being part of a choice block.

Why is `ONLY` required, rather than optional, in this clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I recall correctly, ONLY is required according to the ANSI SQL standard.

If Microsoft made it optional, that may cause problems later on when ANSI SQL adds new features.

Comment: Wrong spec, OFFSET/FETCH was added in ANSI SQL 2008.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I wasn't having any luck finding the relevant standard.  And yes, the 1992 spec has 132 occurrences of " only", none of which relate to this question.

Comment: How much is your curiosity worth? The ANSI SQL standards can only be purchased.

Comment: @JonathanAllen I just saw that in the Wikipedia article on SQL 2008 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008#Documentation).  I found a reasonably useful facsimile here: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit-offset.